# Populating array with nested $each functions and conditionals in Angular with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I'm having a json object I get from a get request in an angular application. It gives me two main attributes `data` and `included`. The `included` object is somehow a relationship with the `data` object. For example `data` shows messages and `included` the senders of those messages. I managed to associate every message with the sender by checking if an attribute from the data object is the same with another attribute in the included object. here is my code

```
$http.get('data.json').then(
  function(jsonAPI) {
    console.log(jsonAPI);
    var dataObj = {};
    var messages = [];

    $.each(jsonAPI.data.data, function(x, data) {
      dataObj[x] = data;
      $.each(jsonAPI.data.included, function(y, included) {
        if (data.relationships.sender.data.id == included.id) {
          dataObj[x].sender = included;
        }
      });
      messages.push(dataObj[x]);
    });

    $scope.newMessages = messages;
  },
  function(errorResponse) {
    // todo handle error.
  }
);
```

I create a new array that contains all the `data` object and also sender's information under the `sender` attribute. The problem is that a new relationship is added called `user_data_template`. I want with a similar way to be able to pass to the `messages` array the corresponding `user_data_template` data. How can I change the above nested $each function to achieve that?

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sHsGqefeILoD5warNgbV?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution. I had to change the code to the following:

```
    $.each(jsonAPI.data.data, function(x, data) {
      dataObj[x] = data;
      $.each(jsonAPI.data.included, function(y, included) {
        if(data.relationships.sender.data.id == included.id && included.type == "user") {
          dataObj[x].sender = included;
        }
        if(data.relationships.user_data_template.data !== undefined) {
          if(data.relationships.user_data_template.data.id == included.id && included.type == "user_data_template") {
            dataObj[x].question = included;
          }
        }

      });
      messages.push(dataObj[x]);
    });
```

And the new [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iFd95d9wI7dGymWA7nDO?p=preview)